# list_filter with choices as values

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a `Billing` model with a boolean field

```
class Billing(models.Model):
    ...
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Statut', default=False, choices=[(True, 'Payée'), ('False', 'Non payée')])
    ...
```

This is Django Admin

```
class BillingAdmin(BaseOnlyModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ['month', 'year', 'date', 'is_paid']
    list_filter = ['is_paid']
    ...
```

`is_paid` is correcly displayed as `Payée / Non payée` when listing

[image]

But for `list_filter` it's translated to `Oui / Non`

[image]

How can I change this behaviour ? I want it to display `choices`, so it would look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix is by implementing a custom list filter

```
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

class BillingStatusFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Statut'
    parameter_name = 'is_paid'

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(is_paid__exact=self.value())
    
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return model_admin.model.STATUS
```

```
list_filter = [BillingStatusFilter]
```